# Should Instance Variables Be Manipulated From a Non-Static Context in Java

Tags: java, constructor, static-methods

Just getting my feet wet with Java so I apologize if this seems a bit naive. I'm trying to get a better understanding of the conventions for accessing instance / member variables in practice.

> **Can a non-static instance variable be manipulated from a
> non-static context?**

For instance, How could one modify the following class definition to allow the id and version variables to increment.

```
    class Foo {
    
        private int id;
        private int version;
        public String product;
        public String model;
    
        private Foo( ) {
    
            // Can these variables be accessed from a non-static context?
            id++;
            version++;
    
        }
        ...
```

In comparison with static fields ...

```
      class Foo {

        private static int id;
        private static int version;
        public String product;
        public String model;

        private Foo( ) {

            id++;
            version++;

        }
        ...
```

First Example ...

> 1
> 1
> Model One
> First
>
> 1
> 1
> Model Two
> Second

Second Example ...

> 1
> 1
> Model One
> First
>
> 2
> 2
> Model Two
> Second

Comment: So all that code is the *minimum* required to demonstrate your question? I didn't think so... it's copy-paste laziness. Please read [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @Bohemian I wasn't intending to be lazy I simply wanted to provide a clear example of what I intended to express. Sorry if it was overly verbose.

Comment: @Bohemian ... Updated ... Better?

Comment: Much better! Much clearer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access a `static-variable` from a `non-static context`, because `static variables` are bound to a class. So, even if you access it within a `non-static context`, it is accessed just like in `static context`.

For e.g: -

```
MyClass obj = null;
obj.staticVar = 10;
```

Surprisingly the above code does not throw `NPE`, as the static varible is accessed on `class name` regardless of how you are accessing it.

So, `obj.staticVar` is actually replaced with `MyClass.staticVar`.

But the reverse is not true. You cannot access a `non-static variable` from a `static context`. Because, in a static context, you don't have any `reference` to an instance. And you can't access instance variable without any reference to an instance of that class.

---

Having said that, also note that, just because you can do something, doesn't mean that it is a good idea. Modifying a `static variable` inside a `constructor` or in any `non-static context` is a `terrible` idea. Because, any change you make to those variables, will be reflected for all the instances of that class.

Rather, you should use a `static-initialization block` to initialize the `static` variables. `Static initialization block` is executed at `class-loading` time, to initialize all the `static` variables.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the should disclaimer ... I'm trying to apply my understanding of the rules of architectural blueprints which state, "Should" means you can; "Shall" means you must.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to mantain those attributes as `static` variables in the class I'd highly discourage you to do so. Those `id` and `version` fields should go in a particular class that manages them, for that object and for every object that would need them.

That way, you can ask your "IdManager" for a new `id` and a new `version` and assign those to the object you created.

Just to answer your question, a `static` field is shared through all the instances of a certain class` so any modification impacts all of the instances.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... I understood that static variables are 'Global' to the class I was quite sure if they could be (or should be) manipulated from an instance of the class. I wouldn't think it to be very wise to do so ...

Answer (score 2):

Static fields are **shared** across instances.

On the contrary, instances fields are closed to **one specific instance scope**.

That's explain why your fields seem "reset" when you get them from a second instance.

So, to increment your first instance's fields, provide some public methods like this one:

```
public void incrementId(){
  id++;
}
```

So that you can achieve your requirement with:

```
fooOne.incrementId(); // id => 2

fooTwo.incrementId(); // id => 2
```

Comment: +1 I like your perspective here ... In this respect could I simply have an abstract class to provide the default ctor fields for all the instances?

Comment: @Eddie B Abstract class will not change the concept. Even if this one contains the instance's fields, they would be closed strictly to their instance scope 'cause abstract class + subclass are "merged" to create one instance. If you really need to share those fields across every instance, make them static.

Comment: @Eddie B I advise you to check for this perfect book: http://www.amazon.com/SCJP-Certified-Programmer-Java-310-065/dp/0071591060    The best I've read to learn basic Java concepts.

Comment: Ordering now ... You rock :-)

Comment: @Eddie B It's really focus on Java 6, but Java 7 doesn't bring a lot of things at all and by the way the new book doesn't exist yet. You're welcome ;)

Answer (score 1):

What you demonstrated is in fact the desired behaviour.

In your first example you declare **instance variables** and increment them in the constructor, **which only affects the instance**.

In your second example you declare **static/class variables** and increment them in the constructor. As you **instantiate the class two times** and each constructor invocation increments the class variables, thus **incrementing them twice**.

Comment: @Bhesh: Thanks for correcting my mistakes. I thought your way and wrote it the wrong way ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want is something like this

```
    private static int globalID;
    private int id;
    private static int version;
    public String product;
    public String model;

    private Foo( ) {

        this.id = globalID;
        globalID++;
        //...
      }
```

Comment: Except that you'd want to use an AtomicInteger and either incrementAndGet() or getAndIncrement() to manage the concurrency.